# How to train an end-to-end deep neural network (FCN) for MatConvNet?

Tags: deep-learning

MatConvNet support convolution transpose layer ('convt'), but I can not find an example in their source code nor in their documents. Are there any guidence?

I noticed there is an example given by https://github.com/vlfeat/matconvnet-fcn,
but it involved many irrelated things. I hope the example to be as simple as possible.

Comment: Were you hoping for a fully convolutional network that did not perform segmentation, or simply an example usage of the convolution transpose layer?

Comment: yes, I want a general purpose FCNN for end to end learning.